# A representation of group as algebraic functions

Tags: representation-theory

I'm currently taking a course on representation theory and I am very confused of how one can represent a group element as a function. A specific question is:

> Show that the functions $φ_1 = 2xy$ and $φ_2 = x^2 − y^2$ transform as one of the irreducible
> representations of the group 32

Also, I'm also not sure how one can use polynomials to work out a matrix representation of a group either. The recipe given is:

Define $f(x, y) = c_1 + c_2x + c_3y + c_4x^2 + c_5y^2 + c_6xy$

• define the dummy variables X and Y by back-rotating x and y, using 2×2 matrices.

• replace x and y with X and Y

• Re-write the rotated polynomials as a function of the original variables x and y.

• Write the generic rotation in the ‘space’ of polynomials as a 6×6 matrix acting on the
coefficients $c_i$

Which is fine, but the question then goes on to repeat this for the mirror operation (K of group 32). In this case how do I define the dummy variables X and Y?

For reference, the course notes are https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/students/course-materials/symmetry-in-condensed-matter-physics with the above two questions being question number 4 and 5 from Sheet 1.

I am very confused with this idea and would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. With $k[x,y]_n$ the homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ and two variables (ie. $k[x,y]_2 = kx^2+ky^2+kxy$) then for $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\in GL_2(k),f(x,y)\in k[x,y]_n$ we have that $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}.f(x,y) = f(ax+by,cx+dy)$ is a representation of $GL_2(k)$ on $k[x,y]_n$, which is indeed irreducible (at least when $k$ has characteristic $0$)

Comment: @reuns Hi, I'm sorry but this is my first introduction to group and representation theory, and I don't understand most of your notation.. To specify my question a little more, I understand group elements as a geometric operation and as matrices, with operations being matrices multiplication. However, I don't understand how algebraic functions can represent group elements. What are the operations in this case? Cheers.

Comment: $k= \Bbb{R}$ and $k[x,y]_2 = \{ ax^2+bxy+cy^2,(a,b,c)\in k\}$ is a subset of $k[x,y]$ where $GL_2(k)$ acts naturally, thus giving an (irreducible) 3-dimensional representation. Then no idea what you mean with $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ and  'the mirror operation (K of group 32)'. Maybe you want some representations of certain subgroups of $GL_2(k)$ ?

Comment: The K element is the mirror operation within the group 32 or D3. The question regarding $\phi_1 \phi_2$ is separate to the second question. May I point you to the first sheet in the link? it might clear some things up.

Comment: So your 'group 32' is $D_3$, the dihedral group with 6 elements, generated by $A=\pmatrix{-1/2&\sqrt{3}/2\\ \sqrt{3}/2&1/2}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\-1&0}$. We have $B.\varphi_1 = -\varphi_1,B.\varphi_2= \varphi_2$. If $A$ sends $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ to the subspace generated by them both then this subspace is a (real, 2-dimensional) representation of $D_3$. If on this subspace $AB\ne BA$ then this representation is automatically irreducible, because if reducible it would be the direct sum of two 1-dimensional representations where $A,B$ commute.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on how you got $B.\phi_1 = -\phi_1$ please?

Comment: I meant $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$

Comment: yep I gathered that, but I still can't see how that happens.. $\phi_1$ is a function not a vector right?

Comment: It is a polynomial. $(B.\phi_1)(x,y) = \phi_1(x,-y)$ is another polynomial